# How can I count the number of invocations for my Lambda Function using the AWS SDK for JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I need to count the number of times a Lambda function in my environment has been invoked in a given date range. Currently, I'm looking at using the [AWS Lambda JavaScript client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/). However, I don't see anything in that SDK that surfaces the invocation count.

Is there a way to surface the number of times a Lambda function was invoked, ideally from JavaScript?

Comment: Use the `Invocations` metrics provided for free in CloudWatch, filtered by `FunctionName` - use the CloudWatch client within the JS SDK to grab this info

Answer (score 0):

To list the number of times a Lambda function has been invoked in a given date range, use the CloudWatch client - [`@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/cloudwatch/) - and the [`GetMetricStatisticsCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-cloudwatch/Class/GetMetricStatisticsCommand/) command.

Set up your [`GetMetricStatisticsCommandInput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-cloudwatch/Interface/GetMetricStatisticsCommandInput/) as such:

- `MetricName` set to `Invocations`
- `Namespace` set to `AWS/Lambda`
- `Period` set to any time range over which to aggregate the data e.g. 10 minutes (600 seconds)
- `Dimensions` set to a one-item array of a dimension with `Key` = `FunctionName`  and `Value` = `[your function name]
- `Statistics` set to a one-item array of `SampleCount`

This will retrieve the number of invocations for a specific AWS Lambda function based on function name, over a specified time period.

If you just need the total count, sum up the `SampleCount` for all the datapoints in the `Datapoints` property on the response ([`GetMetricStatisticsCommandOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-cloudwatch/Interface/GetMetricStatisticsCommandOutput/)).

```js
const { CloudWatchClient, GetMetricStatisticsCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch");

const client = new CloudWatchClient();
const functionName = "lambda-test-function";

const params = {
    MetricName: 'Invocations',
    Namespace: 'AWS/Lambda',
    Period: 600,
    StartTime: new Date('2023-12-09T00:00:00Z'),
    EndTime: new Date('2023-12-11T23:59:59Z'),
    Dimensions: [
        {
            Name: 'FunctionName',
            Value: functionName
        }
    ],
    Statistics: [
        'SampleCount'
    ],
};

(async function main() {
    const request = new GetMetricStatisticsCommand(params);
    const response = await client.send(request);

    const totalCount = response.Datapoints
        .reduce((total, datapoint) => total + datapoint.SampleCount, 0);

    console.log("Response: ", response);
    console.log("Total count:", totalCount);
})();
```

Output:

```json
Response:  {
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'xxx',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Label: 'Invocations',
  Datapoints: [
    {
      Timestamp: 2023-12-10T15:50:00.000Z,
      SampleCount: 11,
      Unit: 'Count'
    },
    {
      Timestamp: 2023-12-10T16:10:00.000Z,
      SampleCount: 5,
      Unit: 'Count'
    }
  ]
}
Total count: 16
```